# Html 5 data-attributes into jquery plugin options format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In addition to jquery plugin options, I want to override those values with html5 data-attributes.

---

This is the desired format for the optionis:

```
var defaults = {
   text: {
      color: 'red',
      opacity: 0.5
   },
   button: {
      width: 100,
      height: 30
   }
}
```

I wanted to format the data-attribute something like this:

```
<div data-text="color:'red', opacity: 0.5"></div>
```

...But you wouldn't be able to read this data `o.text.color` because it simply does not exist. There is however data inside `o.text`.

How could I format the data-attribute so that I can fetch the value with `o.text.color`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an object formatted like a json string to the attribute, and jQuery data will parse it for you.

```
<div class="test" data-test='{ "test1":"Lorem","test2":"Ipsum" }'></div>
```

Also see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBc4E/1/)

Comment: This always happens.. It's something simple and I just couldn't wrap my finger around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt very clean and reminds me of onclick events in HTML. Why not seperate them out into data-test1="Lorem" & data-test2="Ipsum"?

Plugin could be something like this (extending jquery plugin boilerplate):

```
function Plugin( element, options, objD ) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options, objD );
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}

$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
  return this.each(function () {
    if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        var objD = $(this).data();
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options, objD ));
    }
  });
};
```

Im no guru but works well for me

Comment: The reason stems from my desire to use this format: http://pastebin.com/pnEeNje7 for the options, because I find it to be a bit cleaner and easier to remember compared to the usual way of laying them out like this: http://pastebin.com/6DxTvgzL especially if the names are long and there are multiple options.